# MT-135 Sounding Rocket info / design

Tags: engine-design, design, sounding-rocket, jaxa

I'm searching for any design file or deep-info on the MT-135 rocket, the fuel used, engines, engines info, any thing really. I have deep-searched on tons of sites but I just find few missions that used this rocket;  I would like all the possible info. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Are you looking for info beyond what’s on [this JAXA page?](https://www.isas.jaxa.jp/en/missions/sounding_rockets/mt-135.html) It is more detailed than what I usually expect to find about sounding rockets.

Comment: @RussellBorogove yes, i check that page, but im searching info more technical, for example, the name of engines, fuel type, etc..

Answer (score 5):

According to the [JAXA page about the rocket](https://www.isas.jaxa.jp/en/missions/sounding_rockets/mt-135.html), it's a solid-fuel motor:

> The propellant, a pre-formed grain, polyurethane composite with a low burning rate...

By polyurethane composite I assume they mean [HTBP plus ammonium perchlorate and aluminum powder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyl-terminated_polybutadiene), since that's what JAXA generally uses for solid rockets. Since it's a solid rocket stage, the motor itself doesn't have its own name or an identity outside of the MT-135.

The page gives quite a bit of information about the construction as well:

> The [combustion] chamber is built up by welding tubes made of chromium-molybden steel, and the outer edge of the nozzle is welded to it. The throat insert material is graphite, and the exit cone is made of ablative silica-phenolic FRP [fiber-reinforced phenolic, i.e. fiberglass]

The motor casing in the later MT-135P is recoverable by parachute, but the nozzle materials are ablative, so would be replaced after each flight.

Comment: Very usseful info! Thanks for that. And other thing, you have any idea to improve this rocket? i mean, this rocket is from 60's and, maybe a new fuel or something, you have something in mind? just guessing, this answere help me a lot!